# Query Builder Symfony

Tags: sql, symfony

I tried to translate this sql query into symfony, but, I have not succeeded . Can you help me plz !

In my database :

**FichePDF table**
( `id` , `ssocc_id`, `etudiant_id` , `path`)

**Evaluation table**
(`id` , `ssocc_id`, `active`)

`ssocc_id` is a primary key for SousOccasion Table.

my query is :

```
Select * from FichePDF 
inner join Evaluation
ON FichePDF.ssocc_id = Evaluation.ssocc_id;
where Evaluation.active= true ;
```

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below query in your FichePDPRepository, May be it will help you.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('FichePDP')
     ->join('Evaluation', 'e')
     ->where('e.active = :status')
     ->setParameter('status', true)
     ->getQuery();
```